# Не работает кнопка назад в Telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Всем привет, кто то может подсказать, как починить кнопку назад в меню?
Пытался как мог, но ничего не получается

```
from telebot import types # для указание типов
import configure

bot = telebot.TeleBot(configure.config['token']) # токен в файле config


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) #создаем команду
def first_menu(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Узнать сумму к оплате", callback_data = 'sum_opl' )
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Оплатить",callback_data = 'oplata' )
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Передать показания",callback_data = 'per_pokaz' )
    btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Скачать электронную квитанцию",callback_data = 'download')
    btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Регистрация",callback_data = 'reg' )
    markup.add(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте! Что Вы хотите сделать?".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

    types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective= True)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call:True)
def answer(call):

    text = 'Введите номер лицевого счета (9 цифр). Номер лицевого счета можно посмотреть в квитанции.'
    img2 = open('photo2.jpeg','rb')
    btn_menu =  types.InlineKeyboardButton("назад", callback_data = 'menu' )
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

    if call.data == 'sum_opl':         
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'oplata':
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'per_pokaz':
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'download':
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'reg' :
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'menu':
        return

        
        

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Починил. Вот исправный и рабочий код*

```
import telebot
from telebot import types  # для указание типов
import configure

bot = telebot.TeleBot(configure.config['token'])  # токен в файле config


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])  # создаем команду
def first_menu(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Узнать сумму к оплате", callback_data='sum_opl')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Оплатить", callback_data='oplata')
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Передать показания", callback_data='per_pokaz')
    btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Скачать электронную квитанцию", callback_data='download')
    btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Регистрация", callback_data='reg')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте! Что Вы хотите сделать?".format(message.from_user),
                     reply_markup=markup)

    types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=True)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    text = 'Введите номер лицевого счета (9 цифр). Номер лицевого счета можно посмотреть в квитанции.'
    img2 = open('photo2.jpeg', 'rb')
    btn_menu = types.InlineKeyboardButton("назад", callback_data='menu')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

    if call.data == 'sum_opl':
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'oplata':
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'per_pokaz':
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'download':
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'reg':
        markup.add(btn_menu)
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, img2, text, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'menu':
        first_menu(call.message)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Ничего не поменялось, всё равно не работает